# Django Pagination(ordering objects by likes)

Tags: django, django-views

I have a forum where people can ask and answer questions.
So, people who can answer, also can add likes to the posts. I decided to order objects with the number of likes.

And of course, I have a pagination

My views.py

```
def all_questions_max_likes(request):
    all_subjects = Subject.objects.all()
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-likes')
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 4 )
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    posts_ = paginator.get_page(page)
    args = {
        'all_subjects'  : all_subjects,
        'posts'         : posts,
    }
return render(request, 'ask/questions.html', args)
```

This is how it looks like

[image: The image of a page]

Why does Django take an object 3 times, with 3 likes?

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count
posts = Post.objects.all().annotate(num_likes=Count('likes')).order_by('-num_likes')
```